# How to insert an Integer value in SQlite3 (ESP32 - Arduino IDE)?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, arduino, arduino-esp8266

Im trying to create a database which should contains an id (autoincrement) and an integer value by the sqlite3 library.

Now i have troubles to insert an integer value into the const char sql-query.
I tried to insert by %l, but it failed cause of const char type.

```
rc = db_exec(db1, "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (?, %l)", random(0,200));
```

here is the full code:

```
 void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
   sqlite3 *db1;
   int rc;
   SPI.begin();
   SD_MMC.begin();
   sqlite3_initialize();

   if (db_open("/sdcard/test1.db", &db1))
       return;

   //SD_MMC.remove("/test1.db");

   if(SD_MMC.exists("/test1.db")){
    Serial.println("Database exists");
   }else{
      rc = db_exec(db1, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content);");
      if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
         sqlite3_close(db1);
         return;
      }
   }

   rc = db_exec(db1, "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (?, ?)");
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_close(db1);
       return;
   }

   rc = db_exec(db1, "SELECT * FROM test1");
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_close(db1);
       return;
   }

   sqlite3_close(db1);
}
```

the excecute function of database:

```
int db_exec(sqlite3 *db, const char *sql) {
   Serial.println(sql);
   long start = millis();
   int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       Serial.printf("SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
       sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
       Serial.printf("Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   Serial.print(F("Time taken:"));
   Serial.println(millis()-start);
   return rc;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? 
rc = db_exec(db1, "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (" + INTEGER + ", " + WHATEVER + ")");

Comment: rc = db_exec(db1, "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (" + 1234 + ", " + 4568 + ")");

it returns following error:
sqlite3_sdmmc_modified:89:62: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator+'

Comment: can you use a to string() operator ? Maybe that helps?

Comment: the problem is, the function only accepts const char.
`String(integer)` is not working:

see updated function in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string to a const char array. The sample code is below, you can add values with this method.

```
int Value1 = Function1();
int Value2 = Function2();
String s_Command = "INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('" + Value1 + "','" + Value2 + "');";
const char *c_Command = s_Command.c_str();
    
rc = db_exec(db1, c_Command);
```